# ImageView over ImageView

Tags: android

**SOLUTION:** *By adding the drawable in the recyclerview adapter, the drawable is now in the foreground. I think this is causing by recyclerview or picasso.*

There is a CardView with an ImageView inside. 
I want an second imageview over the first which is an icon.

But on the phone it is not visible.

I tried setZ, Elevation, Framelayout, .bringToFront

Nothing works.

Using background in imageview it is showing, but I want to use scrCompat.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardViewWallpapers"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewWallpapers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewViews"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/views" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_views"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingStart="5dp"
            android:text="544"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the order in the XML? Having the `@+id/imageViewViews` view come before `@+id/imageViewWallpapers`?

Comment: @pushasha it goes top to bottom. Top is background and bottom goes to front

Comment: Ah! Sorry, my mistake. I always get it mixed up.

Comment: I copied the XML pretty much line-for-line (except I swapped the FrameLayout for a RelativeLayout, and used a different drawable for the icon), and I could see the icon fine. Just a sanity check -- does the activity that is showing this view extend `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: @pushasha did you tried it on your smartphone?

Comment: Yes, I launched a test app on my phone, Nexus S (API 25).

Comment: @pushasha well it didn't worked on my phone and on multiple virtual deviced. Does maybe picasso or recyclerview causing this problem?+

Comment: If you have double-checked and are absolutely sure that your activities extend `AppCompatActivity`, then yes, it may be something else causing the issue.

Comment: @pushasha I've found a solution. I edited my post with the solution.

Comment: You can actually post an answer to your own question, if you'd like. That way the question will be marked as "answered". Glad you figured out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

By adding the drawable in the recyclerview adapter solved this problem and the imageview is now in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Add `app:srcCompat` to ImageView of `android:id="@+id/imageViewWallpapers"`
and if you want to make image to fit the cardView make the ImageView to `android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

Example:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewWallpapers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/views" />
```